# load different vue component inside another vue component upon user selects an option from select list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vuejs application I have a component called

```
commonform.vue
```

In that form, I have a dropdown list to user to pick a schedule type.

Depending on the user's type selection, rest of the form fields need to be changed.

I have three common fields for all the selected types.

`user name, schedule name and schedule type` , these fields are common and they are in the `commonform.vue`. But rest of the fields are going to be changed according to user's schedule type selection...

I have created **separate vue components** for them as follows in order to avoid too many if-else logics in the `commonform.vue`,

`typeonefields.vue` and `typetwofields.vue`... etc

**My question is,**

How can I load these components inside `fullform.vue` depending on the schedule type selection?

This is my schedule type select

```
<cs-dashboard-select
                                        :options="[
                                            { value: '1', label: 'Type common'},
                                            { value: '2', label: 'Type one'},
                                            { value: '3', label: 'Type two'},
                                            { value: '4', label: 'Type three'},
                                        ]"
                                        name="schedule_type"
                                    > Select type
                                    </cs-dashboard-select>
```

If the user selects Type one, then the form fields should be like,

```
user name, schedule name, schedule type, type one field
```

If it's type two then,

```
user name, schedule name, schedule type, type two field
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by emitting an event from commonform.vue (on scheduled type selection) to fullform.vue and then by using `v-if` you can bind the required component in the DOM.

Here is the implementation logic.

***Parent component (fullform.vue) :***

```
<div>
    <commonform v-on:selected-option="getSelected($event)"></commonform>
    <typeonefields v-if="showComponent === '2'"></typeonefields>
    <typetwofields v-if="showComponent === '3'"></typetwofields>
</div>

methods: {
    getSelected(event) {
      this.showComponent = event;
    }
}
```

***Child component (commonform.vue) :***

```
<cs-dashboard-select
     :options="[
         { value: '1', label: 'Type common'},
         { value: '2', label: 'Type one'},
         { value: '3', label: 'Type two'},
         { value: '4', label: 'Type three'},
     ]"
     name="schedule_type"
     v-model="selectedValue"
     @change="onChange"
> Select type
</cs-dashboard-select>

methods: {
    onChange() {
        this.$emit("selected-option", this.selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer, but I have one small doubt, in my case schedule type drop down is included in the parent vue

Comment: @ArcticFox No, As you said, It will be in your `commonform.vue`. From `commonform.vue` you will emit the event on dropdown selection.

Comment: @ArcticFox Kindly accept this answer if it helps you. So that It will be helpful for other fellow developers as well.